# ejabberd - BOSH module not started

Tags: javascript, facebook, apache, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to create a custom Facebook chat, I'm using:

1. ejabberd
2. strophe
3. apache

The apache is on one pc and the ejabberd is on a different machine, I proxy my request using

```
<Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /http-bind http://my_bosh_domain:5280/http-bind/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://my_bosh_domain:5280/http-bind/
```

I log my requests and get the following error:

```
bosh module not started
```

when I check `http://my_bosh_domain:5280/http-bind/` from my browser I can see:

```
ejabberd mod_http_bind

An implementation of XMPP over BOSH (XEP-0206)

This web page is only informative. To use HTTP-Bind you need a Jabber/XMPP client that supports it.
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

---

I've changed my proxy settings to:

```
   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Proxy>
```

and now I get the following response:

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'
  xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' sid='6093aa55412842f7be3de1b33fd2a307df4ae2fa' wait='60'
  requests='2' inactivity='120' maxpause='120' polling='2' ver='1.8' from='chat.facebook.com' secure='true'
  authid='3105619037' xmpp:version='1.0'>
<stream:features xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
    <mechanisms xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'>
        <mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism>
        <mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism>
        <mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism>
    </mechanisms>
    <c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/'
       ver='TQ2JFyRoSa70h2G1bpgjzuXb2sU='/>
    <register xmlns='http://jabber.org/features/iq-register'/>
</stream:features>
```

this is wrong I was expecting to get X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM as one of the mechanisms.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more then a week of struggle I got it to work, I switched to [punjab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab) instead of the node server and all works fine. so basically the structure is:

Strophe.js <-> Apache (proxy) <-> punjab <-> Facebook XMPP server

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had this problem (I'm having it again now ;-)) the problem was that I needed to add the HTTP host I was trying to access the BOSH server with to the "hosts" configuration option.

Good luck!

Comment: will try it and let you know, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

See [BOSH module not started: Ejabberd / Strophe setup issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101140/bosh-module-not-started-ejabberd-strophe-setup-issue/15107826).

You probably didn't use name@host in the username field in the Strophe page.
Punjab is adding that for you, which makes it work.