# BOSH module not started: Ejabberd / Strophe setup issue

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

Am trying to setup Strophe with Ejabberd on Ubuntu 12 (Linode latest version) using the internal Ejabberd webserver to serve the chat.

The test urls ([http-bind](http://aviezri.org:5280/http-bind) and [admin](http://aviezri.org:5280/admin)) both work.
JWChat works.
Strophe throws an error:

```
In Strophe:
RECV: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' type='terminate' condition='internal-server-error'>BOSH module not started</body>

In ejabberd.log:  
E(<0.468.0>:ejabberd_http_bind:1236) : 
You are trying to use BOSH (HTTP Bind) in host "admin", but the module mod_http_bind is not started in that host. 
Configure your BOSH client to connect to the correct host, or add your desired host`
```

Setup has been straightforward (though it took quite a while to work this out):

1. Installed using sudo apt-get
2. Running under sudo
3. Using the internal server, to avoid messing with proxies or setting up PunJab.
4. In ejabberd.cfg made changes.

Changes to ejabberd.cfg:

```
%% In listening ports, amended the following lines:  
{ request_handlers,  [   
   {["pub"], mod_http_fileserver},   
   {["http-bind"], mod_http_bind}  
]},  

%% In modules, added the following:  
{ mod_http_fileserver, [   
   {docroot, "/var/lib/ejabberd/www"},   
   {accesslog, "/var/log/ejabberd/access.log"}   
]},  
{mod_http_bind,  []},
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is rather obvious.

Strophe requires the username in the following format:

> username@host
>   eg. admin@example.com

It otherwise assumes that the username is really the host, and since such a host doesn't exist, it throws an error that `mod_http_bind is not started in that host`

This error is misleading at best, but it does technically explain the issue.
I was trying to login with just the username [which worked fine in JWChat], hence the issue.

In case this doesn't work, a checklist of some of the other things to verify:

1. Make sure that your domain is added to /etc/hosts

   ```
   127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain   localhost
   12.34.56.78  squire.example.com  squire
   ```
2. Make sure that your domain is added to /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg

   ```
   %% Hostname
   Hostname {hosts, ["example.com","98.765.43.21","localhost"]}.
   ```
3. Ensure that your username exists and is registered:

   ```
   ejabberdctl register username example.com password
   ```

   And if user is an admin, is included in ejabberd.cfg [Note: it must **also** be registered!]

   ```
   %% Admin user
   {acl, admin, {user, "", "localhost"}}.
   {acl, admin, {user, "admin", "example.com"}}.
   ```
4. Check that the server is running:

   ```
   a. sudo ejabberdctl status  
   b. http://example.com:5280/admin  
   c. http://example.com:5280/http-bind
   ```
5. If there are issues, restart using both (I know you don't need both in theory. In practice, sometimes using one or the other would not work right.)

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/ejabberd restart
   sudo ejabberdctl restart
   ```
6. Check the logs - /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166950/connection-failure-when-using-strophe-with-ejabberd-bosh-to-connect-to-jid-accou)).
7. Install JWChat and try that (or, if you have JWChat, install Strophe).
   The following short tutorial is invaluable, follow it exactly: http://www.ejabberd.im/jwchat-localserver